# Custom Rails route query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm putting together a short URL functionality for an app I'm working on and now have it working and turning longer URLs into a short URL by base36 encoding the ID of a record pointing to the longer URL, for example:

http://localhost:3000/7ps -> http://localhost:3000/the/long/url

I am struggling to write a route which will intercept requests for the short URL whilst still allowing requests for other valid URLs in the app.

Is there a route I can use which will only target base36 encoded values after the domain?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add:

```
map.encoded ":encoded_url", :controller => :encoded_urls, :action => :please_decode_me
```

at the end of your routes. Then it shoudl catch everything that is not catched by other routes.

Comment: This is going to fail (in a logical error kind-of way) for the reason I pointed out in my answer.

Comment: @jdl: during creation of new encoded url he can check for forbiden words. It isn't the best solution, but it will work.

Comment: Sure. And then check the list of existing short URLs every time a new controller needs to be added. It can work, but it's tough to maintain, and failures will be silent.

Comment: @jdl: I thought that he stores short urls in table, so he only needs to make it unique.

Comment: @jdl:I see your point about it failing potentially depending on the single word paths.  My app is pretty small so I can probably guard against this by keeping a list of exceptions as I only have a half dozen controllers.  But I certainly take the point - and had considered the idea of an extra path in the URL as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "it depends." You can add a route at the end of your routes file as a catch-all. However, if you have any real routes that are one word long, this will eventually fail.

For example: If you have a path that looks like `http://localhost:3000/home` which is it? Is that the `home` page or the short URL for object #825062? Any single-word path you have in your app is going to have this issue.

A very easy way around this would be to add a single character as the first directory in your URI.

`http://localhost:3000/r/abc123`

Or whatever letter you want. Then you can easily map anything that starts with /r/ to your short-URL lookup controller.

```
map.connect "/r/:short_url", :controller => "controller_name", :action => "name_of_action_that_looks_up_short_urls"
```